# What are Mormons allowed to discuss about the temple, when not inside the temple?

Tags: lds, temple

What are we allowed to discuss or ask questions about outside of the temple?  What things exactly are too sacred to discuss outside the temple, and which things can we talk fairly openly about?

Comment: Could VTCers explain their reasoning? I don't understand why this would be close-worthy.

Comment: Typically, asking "what are we *allowed* to do" in the scope of Christianity is opinion-based, if not off-topic. It's very close to "Is *X* a sin?" questions.

Comment: @Matt Within the scope of LDS opinion. In other words, LDS are the only ones who care about what can be discussed regarding their Temple. That said, the question asks Mormons to discuss exactly that which they would not be allowed to discuss. I think it should be clarified a bit that the question is asking for general topics that can be discussed and general topics that cannot. For example (I'm just making this up) an answer could read "We are allowed to discuss baptism, but not marriage."

Comment: I'm asking on behalf of mormons talking to other mormons too, not just mormons talking to non-members. Example: my brother sat through a session with an apostle in the chapel of the SLC Temple. But he will not discuss what was shared with him unless we are sitting inside the temple. I'm asking mostly on behalf of my own interests, there are questions I would ask about physical items within the temple, what their significance is or what they symbolize.

Comment: Temple symbols point us to Jesus Christ.  Please see https://www.lds.org/youth/article/symbolism-and-temple-preparation?lang=eng -- thanks for your interest!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From [lds.org](https://www.lds.org/church/temples/frequently-asked-questions?lang=eng):

> *What can I say to others about my experience in the temple?*
>
> You can talk about what the interior of the temple looks like, and you can freely share the feelings you have in the temple. However, temple covenants and ordinances, including the words used, are too sacred to be discussed in detail outside the temple. By avoiding discussion of these sacred things outside the temple, we protect them from mocking, ridicule, or disrespect. Do not be casual when talking about your experiences in the temple.

For much more on the topic of temples, what is sacred, and how to treat sacred topics with respect, see the [special edition of the Ensign magazine, October 2010 issue](https://www.lds.org/ensign/2010/10?lang=eng). For pictures, [try a PDF copy of the issue](http://media.ldscdn.org/pdf/magazines/ensign-october-2010/2010-10-00-temples-of-the-church-of-jesus-christ-of-latter-day-saints-eng.pdf).

In particular, see [The Holy Temple](https://www.lds.org/ensign/2010/10/the-holy-temple?lang=eng) by President Boyd K. Packer. He says:

> The ordinances and ceremonies of the temple are simple. They are beautiful. They are sacred. They are kept confidential lest they be given to those who are unprepared. Curiosity is not a preparation. Deep interest itself is not a preparation. Preparation for the ordinances includes preliminary steps: faith, repentance, baptism, confirmation, worthiness, a maturity and dignity worthy of one who comes invited as a guest into the house of the Lord.